# Updating number locally and globally in Vue 2 control

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a component that looks like this:

input-type-a.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <span class="input-group-prepend">
            <button @click="decrementCounter()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-bordercolor btn-number" data-type="minus">
                <span class="fa fa-minus gray7"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <input type="text" :value.number="setValue" :disabled="disabled" class="form-control input-number" @input="$emit('update:setValue', $event.target.value)">
        <span class="input-group-append">
            <button @click="incrementCounter()" :disabled="disabled" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-bordercolor btn-number" data-type="plus">
                <i class="fa fa-plus gray7"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

    export default {
        props: {
            setValue: {
                type: Number,
                required: false,
                default: 0
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {
            incrementCounter: function () {
                this.setValue += 1;
            },
            decrementCounter: function () {
                this.setValue -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
    .gray7 {
        color: #495057;
    }
</style>
```

Where I have an input textbox, two buttons on both sides. On the left side is a button that decrements the count, the button on the right side increments the count.

When I call it from a parent control, the buttons work accordingly, but when I edit the text box inside, it takes the internal value and just adds to that, replacing what I typed in the textbox.

So if I have a default of 36, and I press the increment, it goes to 37, then 38, and so on. Now, if I have a default of 36, and I type in the value to be 50, and I press increment, it goes to 37, then 38, and so on. How do I make it as 50?

I tried using the .sync modified:

```
<input-type-a setValue.sync="0"></input-type-a>
```

but instead I get:

501, then 5011, then 50111, and so on adding + 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're not supposed to modify a props data directly from the child component.

Since you use a [sync prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier), you have to send an event to the parent with the new value of `setValue`.

So your methods will looks like this :

```
incrementCounter: function () {
    this.$emit('update:setValue', this.setValue + 1);
},
decrementCounter: function () {
    this.$emit('update:setValue', this.setValue - 1);
}
```

And secondly, to answer your actual question, your prop is a String in your case.

You have to bind an actual numeric data to the props, or cast `this.setValue` as a number before incrementing / decrementing it.

Here is a working example : https://jsfiddle.net/44ouggkm/

Comment: Thanks for this! I also needed to change @input="$emit('update:setValue', $event.target.value) to @input="$emit('update:setValue', parseInt($event.target.value) || 0)